# Is the legendary raid wins exclusive to normal raid wins in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 403 legendary raid wins as counted in my profile medal but I only have 387 raid wins.

Is the count towards the legendary raid exclusive of the normal raids?

| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
Legendaries do not count for the Champion badge, you have two distinct badges. Other users on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/hbnxs7/is_your_champion_badge_less_than_your_battle/) have noticed the same.

I can confirm this from personal experience, too.